# @keyframes not working in expected way CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm recoding [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_coming_soon.htm) website for practice purposes. I've changed the background image to black in my codepen because images don't work in codepen. [Here's a link to my code.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzZvVm) I've also placed the code here in case you can't view the codepen:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Coming Soon</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background">
      <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>
      <div class="dropdownwrapper">
        <h1 class="bigtext">Coming Soon</h1>
      </div>
      <hr class="divider">
      <h4 class="smalltext">35 days left</h4>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**STYLES.CSS**

```
  body {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.background {
  animation-name: fadeout;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  background-image: url(Images/forestbridge.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
}

.bigtext {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.dropdownwrapper {
  animation-name: dropdown;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.divider {
  border: none;
  width: 20%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.smalltext {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}


@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes dropdown {
  0% {
    margin-top: 10vh;
  }

  100% {
    margin-top: 40vh;
  }
}
```

---

I also have a reset.css, but it's just a standard Eric Meyer 2.0 reset (I've placed it in the codepen, though). My problem is that when you reload the W3Schools version I'm attempting to recode, the text "COMING SOON" comes down, and the line and "35 days left" text stay in place. However, in my code, the entire block of text comes down. Why is the "COMING SOON" text on my site not coming down by itself when I've only selected it's parent div that the other elements are in? How can I make it so that only the "COMING SOON" text comes down?
Thanks,
Lyfe

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are animating the `margin-top` of the `COMING SOON` text. Since the element is in the [normal document flow](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-normal-document-flow), animating the margin gives the impression that the elements after the `COMING SOON` are also being animated, even though they are not. To resolve this, you should be animating using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), which manipulates an element's position `in place`. Check out the [forked codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqoLze).

Additionally, if you wish to centre the entire block of text in the centre of the page, you should wrap all of it an `div` and position it absolutely. I've [forked another codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzZbWr) to demonstrate this.

The slide down effect appears more profound in the second codepen.